# Getting invalid datatype error while parsing xml in Oracle

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to parse XML in PL SQL. But getting following error

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 21, column 43:
PL/SQL: ORA-00902: invalid datatype
ORA-06550: line 17, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I am trying to run below query

```
DECLARE
l_xml xmltype:= xmltype('<Table>
   <Data>
      <DataKey>Test</DataKey>
      <DataTypeID>8</DataTypeID>
      <DataValue>test1</DataValue>
      <Id>eb96c9c1-6236-403d-9afa-6d45ec623dbc</Id>
   </Data>
</Table>');
begin

select * FROM 
xmltable ('/Table/Data' passing l_xml
         columns
          DataKey nvarchar2(50) path '/Data/DataKey'
          ,DataTypeID int, path '/Data/DataTypeID'       
         , DataValue nvarchar2(1024) path '/Data/DataValue');

end;
/
```

I am new to PL/SQL, so not able to figure out the error. Can anybody help me here?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra comma between `int` and `path`:

```
      ,DataTypeID int, path '/Data/DataTypeID'
```

should be

```
      ,DataTypeID int path '/Data/DataTypeID'
```

Or you could use `number` instead of `int`.

Your `select` also has to be selecting *into* something, since this is in a PL/SQL context. So now you'll get a PLS-00428 error. Without knowing what you plan to do with the results it isn't entirely obvious how you should correct that - whether you don't actually need PL/SQL, or you want to loop over the results to do something with them, or insert into another table, or...

Comment: Actually this is part of a bigger query. I was trying to locate the error. Thanks a lot

Comment: OK, then ignore that part, and +1 for isolating the problem and only showing the relevant part of the query *8-)